# Do I need to set something before I can write to an App's Documents-directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have been struggling (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496454/read-write-file-in-documents-directory-problem) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941821/copying-database-from-bundle-to-documents-not-working-cocoa-error-512)) for a while now to get it right to write to my app's documents directory. It always tell me "Not a Directory" even though the code is just copied from a simple tutorial etc.

**Do I need to set anything in the Target or project settings to be able to accomplish this?**

My code works totally fine on the simulator, but not on the actual device.

Comment: Please post your code - may be there is typo that fresh eyes may be able to spot.

Comment: See the links posted, I did do it twice. - But it's ok, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NO**

The problem got solved by setting a non standard Bundle ID in die info.plist

I used the Bundle ID from iTunes Connect for this specific app. Now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it works like a charm to write on the documents directory. No need to setup anything on the project level. The only difference I see regarding the file system is that it is case sensitive on the device and case insensitive on the simulator. Say you want to write in a folder called "Document", if you spell it "document" in your code it is going to work in the simulator (just like it would work if you spelled it "doCumEnt"), but it won't work on the device.